# @ElementCollection of @Embeddables each having @Embeddable field results in "Could not find a setter" exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have entity Ride with @ElementCollection(targetClass = RideLocation.class):

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = RideLocation.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "ride_locations", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ride_id"))
    List<RideLocation> locations = new ArrayList<>();
```

RideLocation is @Embeddable that contains another @Embeddable inside :

```
@Embeddable
public class RideLocation {

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    long timestamp;

    @Embedded
    Location location;

    public RideLocation(long timestamp, Location location) {
        Assert.isTrue(timestamp > 0);
        Assert.notNull(location);
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.location = location;
    }

    RideLocation() {
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

}
```

Location is @Embeddable itself:

```
@Embeddable
public class Location {

    @Column(name = "address")
    String address;

    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    @Column(name = "point", columnDefinition = "geometry")
    Point point;

    public Location(double lat, double lng, String address) {
        this.point = wktToPoint(String.format("POINT(%.6f %.6f)", lng, lat));
        this.address = address;
    }

    Location() {
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public Point getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    @Transient
    public double getLat() {
        return point.getY();
    }

    @Transient
    public double getLng() {
        return point.getX();
    }

    private Point wktToPoint(String wktPoint) {
        WKTReader fromText = new WKTReader();
        Geometry geom = null;
        try {
            geom = fromText.read(wktPoint);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not a WKT string:" + wktPoint);
        }
        geom.setSRID(4326);
        return (Point) geom;
    }

}
```

Looks pretty good, but this configuration gives me an exception "Could not find a setter for property address in class Location".

This looks weird to me since Location had not required setter for any of its properties until I tried to use it inside another @Embeddable that in turn
is the target of ElementCollection.

I.e. second level @embeddable inside colleaction cannot be properly loaded.

UPD stacktrace looks like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class com.dropbyke.application.JpaConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at com.dropbyke.web.api.DropbykeApi.main(DropbykeApi.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.<init>(ComponentMetamodel.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getType(Component.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildStandardProperty(PropertyFactory.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.<init>(ComponentMetamodel.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getType(Component.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.validate(Collection.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Set.validate(Set.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1362)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor28.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1002)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:98)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property address in class com.dropbyke.domain.Location
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createSetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getSetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getSetter(Property.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.buildSetter(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.<init>(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.<init>(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:59)
```

Comment: an Embeddable class is not meant to have corresponding table in database, right? what does the @Column annotation signify here then? I don't understand

Comment: @Prasad Kharkar The column annotation clearly says this field should be stored in a column called whatever the column name is ... so it doesn't have a table, but is persisted into the table of the owner, and has to have a column

Comment: If stating some error message, then stating the JPA implementation being used may help ... since it is that implementation that has the issue. You don't need setters/getters unless using PROPERTY access (and you're not)

Comment: I'm using spring boot starter with hibernate implementation of JPA. All these classes are supposed to persist in db. List<RideLocation> locations collection is inside @Entity Ride.

Comment: Added stack trace, please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: This might be a bug. Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441222/issue-with-jpa-mapping-for-two-nested-embeddable And here might be a related bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9089

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's complaining because you have a field Address with a getter, and no setter. JPA is "smart" enough to assume that methods beginning with "is" and "get" also require a "set" function for the same val. So add a "setAddress" and it'll stop complaining.

To fix this without making a setter, just mark the method as "@Transient". Make sure you import the javax.persistence.Transient one and not the java.beans.Transient one, or it'll still fail.